# suddenly sound got out of sync

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

I was making a animation that I made synced up to a MP3 file. It synced up perfectly, but then when i improved the frame rate, the sync was 2 seconds off. how did that happen!? can I still fix this in video editing after I render my video then import it to the video editing?

Comment: *"when i improved the frame rate"*...that is the answer to your question, but we can't guess what you did there. *"How did this happen?"*... again, without any information on your part it is going to be very hard to tell. It would be easier to help you if you use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information about your project. Is this in the VSE,  Add images that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: I didnt know how to show it with images. I could say theres some scenes that had 4 fps then when i made everything low poly, then the same scene jumped to 13 fps when I played it again

Answer (score 1):

If you set the project frame rate at a given value like 24fps, then add the audio, the sound will be one fixed duration. Then if you alter the frame rate the sound will stretch to fit, however your animation will remain locked at specific frames.

So if you add a keyframe at frame 100 it will always rain at frame 100 even if you change the frame rate.

For example you might have an animation created at 24 fps, then you might want to change frame rate when you add some video that is 30 fps. Now the audio will stretch to match the new frame rate but the animation that you created will not.

Comment: Some hints of a solution may be nice. e.g. "Select all graphs and scale them with S, X, newFPS/oldFPS ..."